# PSD to Al in order to create a vector file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, export

Is it possible to create a logo in  Photoshop and then open the PSD file in Illustrator Al without flattening the layers and then saving it as a PDF and then it is in a vector format?

Comment: Why would you do it? Its easier to just do it in illustrator. But yes you can copyspaste individual items.

Comment: I am still new at this and learning. I have read a lot of comments and will start using Illustrator to make my life easier. I just wanted to convert my old files as I don't have any time to recreate the logos.

Comment: Export as eps and read in in lllustrator.

Comment: Another newbie advice is to _always_ create logos in AI, not PS. You'll understand why as you gain experience.

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/64810/23061

Answer (score -2):

Not possible. The only way is create your logo in photoshop with larger canvas size and high resolution then import and trace with illustrator.